# Chat App with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am learning Firebase Cloud Messaging and I am trying to build a sample chat app.
I could successfully integrate with Firebase and I add messages to Realtime database.

Now to do One to One Chat,

1. Do I need to use Firebase provided Authentication mechanism to add new users?
2. If yes I already have a custom users table, Is there a way to integrate these users with firebase?

Comment: No you don't have to use Authentication i think . You can start with a new child node.

Comment: @ADM, Could you please post as a answer with  some clarity ?

Comment: @ADM While you can use Firebase without authentication, it's incredibly insecure and would mean Firebase would have to be set up with *no* [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) on the nodes you read and write to. That would allow anyone to read and write to those nodes at any time. Please use Firebase authentication for your apps as it provides security and control over the user (and the user experience)

Comment: @jay Thx for clearing ..

Comment: To integrate your custom users table with Firebase, consider using [Firebase custom authentication](). With this, you authenticate the users any way you'd usually do, then [create a token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) that [identifies those users to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) (so that you can secure access to resources based on their user ID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a Google code lab for firebase which is a chat app (Friendly chat). You can find the code lab here:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0

And, the open source project Firechat is also available:

https://github.com/firebase/firechat